# JMeter test works differently from CLI than GUI - why?

Tags: jmeter

I'm creating a small test using JMeter. So far I have one Thread Group that executes an HTTP request, waits for 10 seconds, then executes an other HTTP Request and checks what was returned. If I start 100 such threads with 1 second ramp-up period from the JMeter GUI, it works fine, I get the expected values and the whole test finishes in 22 seconds. However, when I start the very same jmx file from the command line, the test runs for more than 120 seconds and some threads (at the last run, 36 out of the 100) don't get the expected value. This might indicate a bug in the system I test, but I don't understand why the test takes that long time from the CLI and why I get errors from the CLI. What is the difference between running the test from the GUI and from the CLI? Does the CLI run the tests "more parallel"? By the way, this is the command line I'm using:

```
/home/nar/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/jmeter -n -t test_transactions.jmx -l test_transactions.out
```

I'm afraid I cannot share the test plan, but I can share the "outline":

```
+ Thread Group
  + CSV Data Set Config
  + HTTP Request
  | + JSON Extractor
  + Constant timer
  + HTTP Request
  | + JSON Extractor
  | + Response Assertion
  + View Results Tree
  + Save Responses to a file
  + View Results in Table
  + Summary Report
```

The Constant timer waits for 10 seconds. The first HTTP Request sends in some data and initiates a computation, the second checks the result.

Comment: Can you share your test plan? do you use controller and config elements or plugins?

Comment: what are the errors you are getting? did you try removing timer and/or Summary Report and check results?

Comment: The system under test should do some computation between the two HTTP requests. The second HTTP request doesn't return the expected value, that's the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It actually **does indicate the bug in the system under test**. The reason is that you [must run JMeter in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as GUI creates huge overhead in terms of resources consumption, especially when you're using [Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing), especially if one of them is [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree).

So my expectation is that in non-GUI mode you're basically creating more immense load which your application cannot handle. You can check this out using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listeners.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. The parameters of the load are fixed (100 thread groups, 1 second ramp up time), so how could the non-GUI mode generate more load?

Comment: JMeter tries to send requests as fast as it can. In GUI mode `AWT Event Thread` may (and will) block JMeter Threads so JMeter will send requests slower. In command-line mode there is no this overhead so JMeter will send  requests faster.

Comment: But the GUI can start the 100 threads in one second (at least according to the logs) - it's the CLI that doesn't seem to be able to achieve this. The load average on my computer doesn't even reach 1.0 even for the CLI.

Comment: I removed all the Listeners and now I get the same result. I still don't understand why did it help, but helped.

Comment: @DmitriT - You have saidv "JMeter tries to send requests as fast as it can" - I assume this can be controlled by the throughput constant timer?

Comment: It can be controlled but only in one direction. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/) can only **pause** the requests to limit the execution rate to the desired throughput.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should disable the following listeners in non gui test:

- View Results Tree
- Save Responses to a file
- View Results in Table
- Summary Report

After disable you still have result using `-l test_transactions.out` which you can later view using GUI mode with Browse button in your Listener 
[image]

In non GUI you can also generate [dashboard report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) if you want by adding  `-e -o /path/dashboardfolder`

Comment: I loaded the `test_transactions.out` file into the GUI and I just saw that 700 threads were started, not 100. Now that's a higher load, but why does the CLI start 7 times the load as the GUI on the very same .jmx file?

Comment: make sure you save and use same file, and beside that can you show how you thread group looks? maybe you are using different properties